# Ubuntu 19.04 boot time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, time, 19.04

I was wondering if there's something wrong with my Ubuntu booting time. Here's the information I can give you.
[image]

And here's info about the notebook I'm working with:
[image]

I have Dual-Boot with Windows 10.

Can anybody tell me if the startup time is at least decent ? Any way I can improve the time ? Thank you.

Update: I disabled the network manager wait online service.
[image]

Comment: Are you on an ssd or hdd? My i3 laptop takes 3.~~ seconds to boot only, you'rs is a bit higher. (i'm on 18.04 not 19.04)

Answer (score 0):

It's decent, and it can be improved.

One thing which will make your boot feel a little faster is to disable the service "NetworkManager-wait-online" which is waiting for your network to report that it's up and running.

Some services and daemons require networking to be up before they start, and of course if your trying to boot over the network you have to wait for that.  But given that the graphical manager still needs to start and you still need to login and load your desktop, you will never notice that you tried starting this before the network was up.

To disable the service:

`sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service`

If you want it back:

`sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service`

Comment: Great ! Just did that and its some seconds faster. Looking a little bit into the blame command I noticed that two things that are taking the most time are 1_ plymouth-quit-wait.service with almost 19 seconds and 2_ snapd.service with 16 seconds, should I try to see if it's not bad to disable them or its better if i just let it go ? Haha

Comment: @MatiasNuñez I boot with the removal of quiet and splash from the grub command line - I don't see the splash (plymouth) at all, and as a result don't wait for it.